# vb.net /winform DropDown Containing Buttons

Tags: vb.net, winforms

VB.Net / Winform.
Is there a component that will look like a Button but when pressed will open like DropDown, but the DropDown wil contains a list of Buttons? 
Menu bar won't work for me in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Toolstrip with a single ToolStripDropDown button, which contains the list of buttons in the DropDownItems. It won't look exactly like a command button, but you can assign an image to each button. Select No Image Scaling to use the original image size. The Toolstrip defaults as docked, but you can change that and position it anywhere on the form.